# searching on multiple files is too slow using grep

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, grep

I am trying to search 607526 integer entries (saved in array)in multiple files and adding same values and storing in files.It took 1 hr 45 min for 32470 entries and yet not completed. Could you please help me to improve ths script.
Script as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash

my_array=( `grep Curr a.txt  | sed -e 's/Time:\(.*\).Num.*/\1/'` )
my_array_length=${#my_array[@]}
echo $my_array_length

rm -rf output
touch output

for element in "${my_array[@]}"
do
#   echo "${element}"
   toggles=`grep -w "time: ${element}" file_* | awk '{ sum += $6}; END {print sum }'`
   echo "Time:"${element}".Num - "$toggles >> output
done
```

Inptu and Outputs are :

```
a.txt

Curr Time:0.Num - 6274
Curr Time:500.Num - 2
Curr Time:1500.Num - 62
Curr Time:2000.Num - 3
Curr Time:2500.Num - 2
Curr Time:3000.Num - 214
Curr Time:3500.Num - 205
Curr Time:4500.Num - 2
Curr Time:5000.Num - 211
Curr Time:5500.Num - 231


file_0

time: 0 count: 517
time: 2000 count: 9
time: 2500 count: 30
time: 4500 count: 14
time: 5000 count: 2


file_1

time: 0 count: 1500
time: 500 count: 10
time: 1500 count: 25
time: 2500 count: 39
time: 4500 count: 26
time: 5500 count: 154

output

Curr Time:0.NumToggles - 2017
Curr Time:500.NumToggles - 11
Curr Time:1500.NumToggles - 25
Curr Time:2000.NumToggles - 9
Curr Time:2500.NumToggles - 69
Curr Time:3000.NumToggles - 0
Curr Time:3500.NumToggles - 0
Curr Time:4500.NumToggles - 40
Curr Time:5000.NumToggles - 2
Curr Time:5500.NumToggles - 154
```

Image available at https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFxt8.jpg if desired.

Comment: First, you seem to be spawning a lot of redundant processes. I think we can tune this a lot. Second, please give a sample of the input file, and more detail on what you are trying to accomplish. Third - quick tip - rewrite the whole think in `awk` and do it in one pass. (Or perl. Or bash - `read` is slow, but still likely faster than this way.)

Comment: [Don't use images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) People want to copy/paste or download your data so we can use identical files for testing before offering a solution. No one wants to type all that in, even if it's just a fe lines, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked on my git bash emulation. Let me know if it chokes on a full dataset.

```
awk -v keyfile=a.txt ' { sum[$2] += $4; next; }
 END { 
   while ( getline < keyfile && "$0" ) {
     match( $0, "^Curr Time:(.*).Num", key);
     printf "Curr Time:%d.NumToggles - %d\n", key[1], sum[key[1]];
   }
 }
' file_*
```

The logic: make one pass through all the datafiles to sum the values per key. Then one pass through the master file to get the full set of keys, printing the sum for each. This only invokes one primary process for one read through each file, rather than two for an initial load and then two for a complete scan of all the datafiles for *every* key, which is hundreds of thousands of passes through the files.

Questions welcome.

Comment: You're welcome! How does it perform on the real data?

Comment: around 1 min only